# Cin Function in xeus-cling in ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, c++, jupyter

the xeus-cling functions well for output but it is not providing any input box.

[image]

like this so how can i try to run the c++ so that it can take input also

Comment: 1. This is a xeus-cling problem, not a Ubuntu problem. Try posting this to StackOverflow next time. 2. Try disabling or commenting out all previous cells, then shut down and restart this Jupyter kernel